# Measuring the resistance of a thermistor

Tags: electricity

I would like to know why you need to have a resistor in series with a thermistor to measure the resistance of the the thermistor. If you have an ammeter wouldn't that give me the current and i will have the voltage from the voltmeter and i would be able to use V=IR?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The resistor is probably there to prevent 'thermal runaway'. I'll explain…

You want the temperature of the thermistor to be that of its environment if you are using the thermistor set-up as a thermometer, or are trying to calibrate it as a thermometer.

But if there is a current through the thermistor (and therefore a pd across it), power will be dissipated in the thermistor, and this will tend to raise its temperature above that of its environment.

This effect will usually be negligible, because the current will usually be very small. But the commonest sort of thermistor, the ntc type, has a resistance that decreases with increasing temperature. So if the thermistor is connected straight across a constant voltage source (a battery is pretty nearly such a source), the power dissipation ($V^2/R$) will increase as the temperature of the environment increases. The power dissipation may no longer be negligible, and may make the thermistor significantly hotter than its environment. This 'self-heating' will cause further temperature rise and more power dissipation, so the thermistor gets hotter and hotter… Thermal runaway!

The series resistor will limit the current and (if properly chosen) prevent significant self-heating.